# Using ranges with std::set

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to initialize `std::set` with several ranges of numbers. I would like to do it efficiently (minimal copying), without using `boost` and with good code readability for the end-user (myself :) at the moment).

Following is what I've come up with so far, but I can see a number of inefficiencies and wanted to get pointers on whether it is possible and how to fix them. Specific questions are below the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

typedef std::set<int> codes;

template<typename T>
inline codes operator|(codes&& x, T&& y)
{
    codes c(std::move(x));
    c.insert(y.begin(), y.end());
    return c;
}

template<typename T>
inline codes operator|(const codes& x, T&& y)
{
    codes c(std::forward<T>(y));
    c.insert(x.begin(), x.end());
    return c;
}

inline codes range(int min, int max)
{
    codes c;
    for(int ri = min; ri < max; ++ri) c.insert(ri);
    return c;
}

void print_set(const std::string& name, const codes& set)
{
    std::cout << name << " = ";
    for(int ri: set) std::cout << ri << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    codes r1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    codes r2 = range(5, 10);
    codes r3 = r1 | r2;
    codes r4 = r2 | range(15, 20);
    codes r5 = range(1, 10) | r1;
    codes r6 = range(1, 5) | range(10, 15);

    print_set("r1", r1);
    print_set("r2", r2);
    print_set("r3", r3);
    print_set("r4", r4);
    print_set("r5", r5);
    print_set("r6", r6);

    return 0;
}
```

1. I wrote the `operator|` as templates to deal with various combinations of r- and l-value references. However, the `operator|(&& x, && y)` version still has to copy the elements from `y`. Is it possible to avoid it?
2. The `range` function executes at run-time. Is it possible to write a `constexpr` version that runs at compile-time?
3. Anybody sees any other things that can be optimized?
4. Should I use an entirely different approach?

The key things are:

a) The code should be easily readable. In other words it should somewhat resemble the mathematical expression, eg: `foo = [a, b) | [c, d)`

b) The program will run on an embedded system, so code footprint and efficiency is important (hence, no `boost`).

Comment: codes r3 = r1 | r2;
codes r4 = r2 | range(15, 20);   Let's say r2 is not copied but moved, then your 2nd statement would become invalid right ?

Comment: @Jagannath, `r2` is an l-value, so it wouldn't be moved. `range(15, 20)` on the other side should be moved. That's why I have several versions of the `operator|` to deal with various situations. Obviously there are cases where copy cannot be avoided.

Comment: I don't think we can put our own things into the `std` namespace except template specialization, don't we?

Comment: *"`operator|(&& x, && y)` version still has to copy the elements from `y`. Is it possible to avoid it?"* - you could store ranges as say `std::set<std::pair<int,int>>` of build merging logic to maintain a minimal set of non-overlapping ranges, then only expand it when absolutely necessary.  (I've done that in 2D before for tracking cell selections in huge grid widgets.)

Comment: @NickyC, you are correct. I tweaked the question

Comment: @TonyD, I thought about doing this, but it seemed a lot more complicated. Thank you for this idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of this:

```
template<typename T>
inline codes operator|(codes&& x, T&& y)
{
    codes c(std::move(x));
    c.insert(y.begin(), y.end());
    return c;
}

template<typename T>
inline codes operator|(const codes& x, T&& y)
{
    codes c(std::forward<T>(y));
    c.insert(x.begin(), x.end());
    return c;
}
```

Could be written as:

```
template<typename T>
inline codes operator|(codes x, T&& y)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    x.insert( begin(y), end(y) );
    return x;
}
```

Passing `codes x` by value will implement the correct and already-well-tested `std::set` constructors for both lvalues and rvalues.

Comment: Drew, nice one. `+1` for you sir.

Comment: Drew, why `std::begin(y)` and not `y.begin()`?

Comment: @InnocentBystander It is more idiomatic.

Comment: @NickyC, please elaborate

Comment: @InnocentBystander a type such as the C array `int[3]` would not have a `begin` member function.  But it would work here.

Comment: @DrewDormann Edited your answer to allow ADL-overloads. Please rollback if you don't agree.